# Whats App chatbot with twilio function to login into 3rd party web application

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

Need guidance to develop `whatsApp` chatbot to login into a 3rd party application using `twilio` functions.

Whenever a user sends whatsApp message to `twilio` number I want to login into 3rd party web application and query necessary data and respond back to the user with query response. Since the web application doesn't have any REST API implementation I cannot use `axios` or any 2FA authentication to log in. Authentication should be done by through browser. Currently, I don't have a clue to how to login dynamically.

Tried to do with puppetter.js, cypress.js, nightwatch.js, but no luck.

This is an web application where LCO's can login and activate/de-active/payment for their customer STB boxes. They don't have any 2FA, service based architecture. All can be done by login into their web application only.

Through puppeteer/nightwatch/cypress i tried opening browser window dynamically to login into the system. I have a standalone cypress spec to open the browser and login dynamically. All these steps i want to do with help of twilio functions.

Below is the flowchart.

Customer Send whatsapp message to twilio number
- STB ACTIVATE 6983784934
- Twilio function to open url in background
- Login with credentials
- Search STB 
- Activate STB by clicking activate button in screen 
- Take screenshot of the updated status
- Send screenshot with success message to End user

Comment: Can you explain what "web application" you're talking about? What's the 3rd party service you're trying to connect? Where are Twilio functions in there?

Comment: What exactly did you try in puppeteer, cypress or nightswatch? Can you show the code?

Comment: I have edited my original question with more information for better understanding.